# Android reschedule a one-time notification for a different date after it has been broadcast?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-notifications, repeat

I have managed to make one time and repeating notifications work fine, but to repeat every month I believe we need to set the notification again as a one time notification because some months are 30 days and other 31 etc. So the idea is when an alarm is initially set, the current month is used, and based on that we can set the `AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY` + 31 or + 30 etc. But the problem with this is that it will repeat this alarm every 31 days. So i think if we set it as one time alarm and once the alarm goes off, we can re-schedule the same alarm but only changing the `AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY + (currentMonthsNumberOFDays)`.

What will be the best way to do this in the background once the original alarm has gone off? Here is the `BroadcastReceiver` which works one for one time notifications, and repeating notifications except repeating every month.

```
package com.mypackage.myapp;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class NotificationPublisher extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static String NOTIFICATION_ID = "notification-id";
    public static String NOTIFICATION = "notification";

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Notification notification = intent.getParcelableExtra(NOTIFICATION);
        int id = intent.getIntExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, 0);
        notificationManager.notify(id, notification);
        System.out.println("Notification ID is: "+ id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. I am not sure if it's the best way, but it works.

I have added the following to the BroadcastReceiver

```
 Long futureTimeDifference = intent.getLongExtra("futureTimeDifference", 0); // Receive the time difference in milliseconds from currenttime in milliseconds and the future set date milliseconds
    futureTimeDifference = futureTimeDifference + System.currentTimeMillis();// get the next schedule date time inmilliseconds
    String repeatType = intent.getStringExtra("getRepeatType");// Receive the repeat type

if(repeatType.equals("mondayToFriday")) {
        //handled in NotificationPublisherWeekDays BroadcastReceiver
    }
    else if(repeatType.equals("saturdayAndSunday")) {
        //handled in NotificationPublisherWeekEnd BroadcastReceiver
    }
    else if(repeatType.equals("oneMonth")) {

        Date todaysDate = new Date();// initialize a new date object
        Calendar getCurrentDate = Calendar.getInstance();// Initialize a new Calendar object
        getCurrentDate.setTime(todaysDate); //Set the calendar to todays date
        int currentMonth = getCurrentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH); // Assign the current month in integer

        if (currentMonth == Calendar.JANUARY || currentMonth == Calendar.MARCH || currentMonth == Calendar.MAY || currentMonth == Calendar.JULY || currentMonth == Calendar.AUGUST || currentMonth == Calendar.OCTOBER || currentMonth == Calendar.DECEMBER){
            futureTimeDifference = System.currentTimeMillis() + (AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 31);
        }
        if (currentMonth == Calendar.APRIL || currentMonth == Calendar.JUNE || currentMonth == Calendar.SEPTEMBER || currentMonth == Calendar.NOVEMBER){
            futureTimeDifference = System.currentTimeMillis() + (AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 30);
        }

        if  (currentMonth == Calendar.FEBRUARY){//for february month)
            GregorianCalendar cal = (GregorianCalendar) GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
            if(cal.isLeapYear(2015)){//for leap year february month
                futureTimeDifference = System.currentTimeMillis() + (AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 29);
            }
            else{ //for non leap year february month
                futureTimeDifference = System.currentTimeMillis() + (AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 28);
            }
        }

    }

    // If it is not a one time notification (repeat is not off) reschedule the notification
    if(!repeatType.equals("Off")) {

        AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent rescheduleNotificationIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationPublisher.class);
        rescheduleNotificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION_ID, id);
        rescheduleNotificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION, notification);
        PendingIntent rescheduleNotificationPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, rescheduleNotificationIntent, 0);
        alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, futureTimeDifference, rescheduleNotificationPendingIntent);
        System.out.println("Alarm set again - futureTime is: " + futureTimeDifference);
    }
```